# How to get the command line to interpret & as a string without explicitly making it a string

Tags: python-3.x, shell

Everytime I run my script and try to pass a `&` symbol to the end of my command line args it gives back what I believe to be some sort of process ID.

This is my script:

```py
import sys

s = sys.argv[1:]
print(s)
```

And I run it like this:

```
$ python3 shell.py hello.sh &
[2] 3211
["hello.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand sign `&` tells the shell to fork itself and run the job in the background. It also prints you the number of the job and its process ID (PID).

If you need more information about job control in a shell, take a look [at this blog post](https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html).

If you wand to pass it as argument to your program, you need to escape it first with a backslash:

```
$ python3 test.py  hello.sh \&
['hello.sh', '&']
```